# nav bar rendering differently across different browsers

Tags: css, html

I'm developing [a new website](http://www.miafurnishings.com).

Testing out the page in different browsers, I find that the nav bar renders differently depending on the browser.  In Chrome and Safari it looks correct, but in Opera, IE and Firefox the nav bar renders differently.  I've validated the HTML, I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: How are you coming along with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a problem with floats after unfloated content - very similar to a question I just answered:

[CSS issue with IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089945/css-issue-with-ie8/11090111#11090111)

Let me know if reviewing that question gets you going in the right direction.

Comment: there are a lotta things which are wrong with the site.. not only with floats..!!.. and his elements are not in div's.. they are `ul's and li's`

Comment: @VivekChandra: perhaps, but I am attempting to answer his question, not delve into other problems - I assume it's a work in progress.

Comment: your answer is just 1 step in the solution.. looking @ his site,your yet to provide him 10-15 step's if you want to answer his question..

Comment: I'll take your word for it - certainly there are numerous "problems."  If Tony could post a stripped-down test case demonstrating the problem to jsfiddle I might be tempted to slog through a bit more of it.

Comment: Thank you both for your help - it was an issue of floats and unfloated content.  It is something of a work in progress, and if it's not completely obvious I'm a novice at this and I'm learning as I go...  If I may - what would be the next thing to look at?  I obviously don't recognize the problems you do...  Thanks again.

Comment: Your use of html5 and validation tools is commendable.  Perhaps a good next step would be to follow some of the advice here:
https://developers.google.com/speed/

You need not follow it all, but it's good general advice and getting a 100% score on google's speed test is a great learning experience.

I see no problem using ul/li for nav flyouts, I do that myself without trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Your UL is styled up in the right corner.  In IE hit F12 and start going through the +'s of code and you can find under nav role, the UL is way off to the right.  I would start editing CSS in the nav role and ul first.